# Why is the induced Hilbert space norm $\|\cdot\|^2$ strictly convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H, \langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle)$ be a Hilbert space with the induced norm defined by $v \mapsto \|v \| := \big( \langle v, v \rangle \big)^{1/2}$.

How can we show that $\| \cdot \|^2$ is strictly convex?

Comment: Have you tried writing out what it means for the norm to be strictly convex, squaring and expanding in terms of the inner product? You should get something that is straightforward to estimate.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I had done that, but didn't notice how you can regroup all the terms on one side to get a nice factorization.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v, w \in H$ with $v \neq w$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$.
\begin{align*}
&\alpha \|v\|^2 + (1-\alpha) \|w\|^2 - \|\alpha v + (1-\alpha)w\|^2 \\
= &\alpha \|v\|^2 + (1-\alpha) \|w\|^2 - \big( \alpha^2 \|v\|^2 + (1-\alpha)^2 \|w\|^2 + 2\alpha(1-\alpha) \langle v,w \rangle \big) \\
= &(\alpha - \alpha^2) \|v\|^2 + \underbrace{\big((1-\alpha) - (1-\alpha)^2\big)}_{= \alpha - \alpha^2} \|w\|^2 - 2 \alpha(1-\alpha)\langle v,w \rangle \\
= &\alpha(1-\alpha) \big( \|v\|^2 + \|w\|^2 - 2\langle v,w \rangle \big) \\
= &\alpha(1-\alpha) \underbrace{\|v - w\|^2}_{\substack{\neq 0 \\ \textrm{since $v \neq w$}}} >0
\end{align*}
That is 
$$
\|\alpha v + (1-\alpha)w\|^2 < \alpha \|v\|^2 + (1 - \alpha) \|w\|^2,
$$
so $\|\cdot\|^2$ is strictly convex.

**Note:** We didn't require completeness, so this holds for any inner product space.